# Django add a field to a model based on another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a model  for a product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Name"), max_length=120)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="name", verbose_name=_("Slug"), always_update=False, unique=True)
```

I want to have a separate model ProductFields:

```
class ProductFields(models.Model):
   field_name = models.CharField()
   field_type = models.CharField()
   field_verbose_name = models.CharField()
   field_max_length = models.IntegerField()
   filed_null = models.CharField()
   field_blank = models.BooleanField()
   field_default = models.CharField()
...
```

So the idea is whenever I add new ProductField I want Product model to migrate that added field to its database.

For Example:

```
ProductFields.objects.create(field_name='description', field_type='CharField', field_verbose_name='Description', field_max_length=255, filed_null=True, filed_blank=True)
```

This should transform Product modal to:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Name"), max_length=120)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="name", verbose_name=_("Slug"), always_update=False, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name="Description", max_length= 255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Please let me know if you have any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to create a dynamic model you can look into these suggestions.

1. **HStoreField using django-hstore** : https://django-hstore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
2. **JSONField**: JSONField is similar to HStoreField, and may perform better with large dictionaries. It also supports types other than strings, such as integers, booleans and nested dictionaries.https://django-pgfields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#json-field

Or you can use a NoSQL database (Django MangoDB or another adaptation)